# pycairo. Проблема со вставкой изображения png

Tags: python, изображения, png, cairo, pycairo

Перед cr.save() есть указание масштаба cr.scale(mm, mm), переводящее все единицы к миллиметрам. Вся работа ведется так. Далее..
Создаю поверхность с картинкой:

```
img = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png("img.png")
```

Картинка имеет размер 101x492px, но вставляется с размером 101x492mm (кажется)
Я пробовал менять масштаб через img.set_device_scale(scl, scl) и cr.scale(scl, scl), вариации с числами масштаба  дают нужный размер, но у меня никак не получается выяснить точные размеры изображения (для центрирования), не могу понять как это всё работает.

Далее часть кода где я хочу вставить в прямоугольник изображение ровно по центру, для этого мне нужно знать ширину прямоугольника и ширину изображения после скейлинга. Со вторым возникли проблемы.

```
import cairo

a4w, a4h = 210, 297
mm = 72/25.4

surface = cairo.PDFSurface(pdfname, a4w*mm, a4h*mm)
ctx = cairo.Context(surface)

cr.scale(mm, mm)

cr.translate(30, 30)
cr.set_line_width(0.1)
cr.set_source_rgb(0, 0, 0)
cr.rectangle(0, 0, 49, 74)
cr.stroke()

cr.translate(3, 16)
cr.rectangle( ((49-6)/2)-(35/2), 0, 35, 7)
cr.stroke()

cr.save()

imgsf = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png(exlogo)
# далее я пытаюсь выставить середину
print(imgsf.get_height(), 'x', imgsf.get_width(),
      '--- scale =', imgsf.get_device_scale())
# wcenter = ((49-6)/2)-(imgsf.get_width()/2)
# inpx = (96/2.54)/10
# inpx = imgsf.get_height()/96*25.4/7
# card_width = inpx*43
# exl_width = imgsf.get_width()/inpx
# wcenter = (card_width/2)-(exl_width/2)
# print(card_width, exl_width, wcenter)
# самое магическое тут число 35, которое как раз нужно определить как ширину изображения
cr.translate(((49-6)/2)-(35/2), 0)
# sclc = 1 / (imgsf.get_height() / 7)
# cr.scale(sclc, sclc)
scl = (imgsf.get_height() / 7)
imgsf.set_device_scale(scl, scl)
cr.set_source_surface(imgsf, 0, 0) 
cr.paint()

cr.restore()
# ...

surface.write_to_png(fileobj)
```

....

Вот примерно такие попытки были найти точную ширину. Но то ли у меня с математикой фигово, то ли запутался в край, но убито полдня, а ширину так и не научился нормально определять (разве что через inkscape).

Есть ли более простой способ вставки изображения, или может кто то объяснить как с этим работать?

Дополнение:
Всё просто оказалось.

```
cr.save()
imgsf = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png(img)
scl = (imgsf.get_height() / 7)
exl_width = imgsf.get_width()/scl
cr.translate( ((49-6)/2)-(exl_width/2), 0 )
# imgsf.set_device_scale(scl, scl)
cr.scale(1/scl, 1/scl)
cr.set_source_surface(imgsf, 0, 0)
cr.paint()
cr.restore()
```

Вот это сработало. Причем неважно какой скейлинг применять, результат одинаково удовлетворительный. Хотя я так до конца и не разобрался с этими цифрами. Если кто то сможет по-простому объяснить, буду признателен.

Comment: Ого, кто-то cairo пользуется :) Оформите, пожалуйста, свое решение как ответ :)

Comment: Если не секрет - А чем нужно пользоваться?

Comment: Я до этого использовал связку svgwriter + cairopdf и почти всё получилось, но решил перекодить на cairo поскольку у svgwriter не нашел функционала для определения размеров отрендеренного текста, а во-вторых pycairo умеет сразу в pdf гнать. Но вот с изображениями какая то фигня. Теперь не могу вставить изображение из BytesIO либо PIL либо numpy. Выход либы позволяет все три варианта, а в pycairo никак это дело нормально не втыкается. Видимо буду новый вопрос писать скоро.

Comment: Не поймите неправильно, для вашей задачи это самое то, просто ооооочень редко, по моему в первый раз, вижу тут задачу по cairo :)

Answer (score 2):

У меня заработало так:

```
cr.save()
imgsf = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png(img)
scl = (imgsf.get_height() / 7)
exl_width = imgsf.get_width()/scl
cr.translate( ((49-6)/2)-(exl_width/2), 0 )
# imgsf.set_device_scale(scl, scl)
cr.scale(1/scl, 1/scl)
cr.set_source_surface(imgsf, 0, 0)
cr.paint()
cr.restore()
```

Пускай будет ответом.